# Yum's download speed is too slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, package-management, yum

My yum download speed is in average less than 5KBps and goes to less than 1KBps but my normal download speed is around 140KBps. I tried installing yum-fastestmirrors but didn't help. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Yum Download speed issue solution:**
It's depends on the mirrors your downloading from. They either could be slow or fast.
You might try "yum install yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch" and see if that gives you more speed.

Comment: as I said I did that but made no difference

Comment: Once the installation completed (yum-plugin-fastestmirror) or (yum-fastestmirror), you have to edit the file /etc/yum.conf and add the following line to the file:
plugins=1